# how to get client ip for different kinds of clients

Tags: glassfish, client, ejb, ip, java-ee-5

How Can I get client ip in an ejb interceptor? My application is based on javaee5 and is deployed on glassfish and it has different kind of clients (*ejb/MDB/jax-ws webservices*) and I have a default interceptor that is responsible to log client ip and etc. Can I use **java.rmi.server.RemoteServer**? I test it but I'm getting this error :

**`ServerNotActiveException: not in a remote call`**

Any Idea?

Comment: Not sure this is possible. I don't think the EJB container has access to even the HTTP request, so I believe it might be not possible to retrieve the client's IP address

Comment: Even if I use a soap handler and put a value into Message context and get it in the interceptor? Can I get the access to client IP in soap handler?

Comment: If you are exposing your EJB as a web service -which is what I understand from your reply-, you can get the ip address in the service itself by injecting the @Resource WebServiceContext. This gives you access to the servlet request, which contains a getRemoteAddr() method, which returns the client ip address. No need to use a soap handler then.

Comment: I am sure the previous comment gives a solution (why isn't it an answer?!?). Just for the sake of completeness: RemoteServer.getClientHost can only be used while handling an incoming RMI call within the thread that is handling the RMI call.